# Section with reference to manpages, official documentation

Tags: feature-request

I think there should a section above or below posts/answers with the option to add link(s) to (if any) manpages and/or official (or a similar) documentation to command used in the answer as this will be informative to the OP and future users looking for an answer. Also, this will sort out the problem of useful links getting lost in long answers!

Comment: Perhaps post a community question / answer on where to go for additional official documentation ?